# How to do value counts on certain words in a dataset

Tags: python, loops

I have two problems

1.) Need to get value counts for how many times a word appears in my csv on customer reviews.  The words that I want value counts on are :

`keywords= ["big","hat",'dress',"fabric","color"]`

The name of my dataframe is "shopbop" and the column is "review_mo"

2) Would like to create a separate column called "keyword_terms" in the dataframe that returns which words in the "keywords" appeared in the "review_mo" cell and display them under a new column called "keyword_terms".

For instance if in the review if the word "big" and "color" were used I would like on that corresponding row under the "keyword_terms" (big,color) to appear there and do that for all the rows where those terms may apply.  Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do

```py
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue'])
print(counter)
```

with out loop

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `list.count()`

```
data = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

print(data.count('a'))
```